# Why sum is not displaying after aggregation & pivot?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Here I have student marks like below and I want to transpose subject name column and want to get the total marks also after the pivot.

Source table like:

```
+---------+-----------+-----+
|StudentId|SubjectName|Marks|
+---------+-----------+-----+
|        1|          A|   10|
|        1|          B|   20|
|        1|          C|   30|
|        2|          A|   20|
|        2|          B|   25|
|        2|          C|   30|
|        3|          A|   10|
|        3|          B|   20|
|        3|          C|   20|
+---------+-----------+-----+

Destination:
+---------+---+---+---+-----+
|StudentId|  A|  B|  C|Total|
+---------+---+---+---+-----+
|        1| 10| 20| 30|   60|
|        3| 10| 20| 20|   50|
|        2| 20| 25| 30|   75|
+---------+---+---+---+-----+
```

Please find the below source code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val list = List((1, "A", 10), (1, "B", 20), (1, "C", 30), (2, "A", 20), (2, "B", 25), (2, "C", 30), (3, "A", 10),
      (3, "B", 20), (3, "C", 20))

val df = list.toDF("StudentId", "SubjectName", "Marks")
df.show() // source table as per above

val df1 = df.groupBy("StudentId").pivot("SubjectName", Seq("A", "B", "C")).agg(sum("Marks"))
df1.show()

val df2 = df1.withColumn("Total", col("A") + col("B") + col("C"))
df2.show // required destitnation

val df3 = df.groupBy("StudentId").agg(sum("Marks").as("Total"))
df3.show()

df1 is not displaying the sum/total column. it's displaying like below.
+---------+---+---+---+
|StudentId|  A|  B|  C|
+---------+---+---+---+
|        1| 10| 20| 30|
|        3| 10| 20| 20|
|        2| 20| 25| 30|
+---------+---+---+---+
```

df3 is able to create new Total column but why in df1 it not able to create a new column?

Please, can anybody help me what I missing or anything wrong with my understanding of pivot concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour from spark pivot function as **`.agg`** function is applied on the **`pivoted columns`** that's the reason why you are not able to see sum of marks as new column.

Refer to [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html) link for official documentation about pivot.

***Example:***

```
scala> df.groupBy("StudentId").pivot("SubjectName").agg(sum("Marks") + 2).show()
+---------+---+---+---+
|StudentId|  A|  B|  C|
+---------+---+---+---+
|        1| 12| 22| 32|
|        3| 12| 22| 22|
|        2| 22| 27| 32|
+---------+---+---+---+
```

In the above example we have added 2 to all the pivoted columns.

***Example2:***

To get count using pivot and agg

```
scala> df.groupBy("StudentId").pivot("SubjectName").agg(count("*")).show()
+---------+---+---+---+
|StudentId|  A|  B|  C|
+---------+---+---+---+
|        1|  1|  1|  1|
|        3|  1|  1|  1|
|        2|  1|  1|  1|
+---------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: if in that case, I need to use df2 logic for to getting total marks as a separate column?

Comment: @Ravi, Yes, needs to do that to get total marks as separate column!

Comment: @Ravi,Did the answer helped? If yes accept the answer to close the thread :)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The .agg followed by pivot is applicable only for the pivoted data. To find the sum you should you should add new column and sum it as below.

```
val cols = Seq("A", "B", "C")

val result = df.groupBy("StudentId")
  .pivot("SubjectName")
  .agg(sum("Marks"))
    .withColumn("Total", cols.map(col _).reduce(_ + _))

result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---------+---+---+---+-----+
|StudentId|A  |B  |C  |Total|
+---------+---+---+---+-----+
|1        |10 |20 |30 |60   |
|3        |10 |20 |20 |50   |
|2        |20 |25 |30 |75   |
+---------+---+---+---+-----+
```